# Position a div outside a modal /relative to its position?

Tags: jquery, css

I've been doing some reading about appending a div to other objects. What I want to do is put a logo on top of a modal box (outside of it), and make it move as the modal changes height. However, I am stuck as to how I would style that to always follow the dynamic modal.

This is what I've got so far:

```
$(#mydiv).appendTo("#cboxContent");
```

What I understand is that this connects them somehow, I've looked up css and jquery and they all seem to do this where both divs are inside a wrapper, however I don't think that applies here. Thanks :)

---

[Not working demo](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/like2)

Added this to the  tag.

```
$(#facebooklike).appendTo("#cboxContent");
```

Added this to #facebooklike:

```
position:absolute;
left:-100px;
top:-100px;
```

---

[Working demo](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/like/)

http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/like/style/colorbox.css

[http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/like/js/jquery.colorbox.js](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/like/style/colorbox.css)

This is the link to the modal:

```
<a class='modal1' href="file2.html">Colorbox</a>
```

And below that I have the facebook floating div:

```
<div id="facebooklike" class="facebooklike">
    <div class="facebookinner">facebook div
</div></div>
```

Comment: Can you reference the modal code and paste what you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code, although it should be $('#mydiv'), positions the div inside #cboxContent.
you could now set the css to:

```
#mydiv{
    position:absolute;
    left:-100px;
    top:-100px;
}
```

for example.

this should display it outside of cboxContent. you'll have to adjust the left and top to fit your needs. also make sure the cboxContent has `overflow:visible;`

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't seem to work. See my working demo above. I added the css properties to #facebooklike and added the 'append to' inside the <script> tags. That breaks the modal.

Comment: Actually, it does work - only not on my modal but that's a different issue. Thanks a lot Andy :)